# front controller reached 100 router match iterations - but only for /admin (adminthml)

Tags: error, adminhtml, controllers, magento-1.4

I have searched for the source of this error and there are several posts but they seem to cover things generally.

In my case, there are some different factors and I'm asking in hopes of not trying to "patch" core.  BTW I have version 1.4.

The front end of the site works fine!  It's only when I try and go to:

```
http://shop-staging.mysite.com/admin
```

That I get this error "front controller reached 100 router match iterations"

Note that we have other deployments of the exact same code base (for example the production `shop.mysite.com/admin`) and it lives quite comfortably in the other environments for both frontend and adminhtml portions of the site.

Is this a database issue?

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried already? Is this Enterprise?

Make sure permissions are right, clear `/tmp`, and manually remove cache, APC or OPcache and try again. Issue is probably not in the codebase if it works somewhere else.